# Help with Red5 installation of Ubuntu

Tags: red5

I tried to install Red5 on Ubuntu server using the steps given in below url-
http://sandeepghael.com/2009/07/getting-red-5-up-and-running-on-ubuntu-9-04/

I followed all the steps but when i try to access the page using 
http://myip:5080/ i am not able to connect.

Browser says - 
The connection has timed out
The server is taking too long to respond.

I have even disabled the firewall. But still haven't got the desired output.

Can anyone please let me know what might be the issue?
Your quick response will be really helpful.

Thanks,
Atul

Answer (score 0):

May I know the output when you running red5.sh?

if it's shows error, first you should kill all red5 process. then run again red5.sh.

Comment: I have the same problem. I can telnet on http://myip:5080. Also I noticed a `...Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.net.BindException: Address already in use` at the end of the `/usr/share/red5/red5.sh` output

Comment: I never get something like that, but maybe, red5 in that path is already running, check with `ps aux | grep red5.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Sometime there are issues with paths. 
start red5 in the dist folder. you can run it in the ssh by typing `/usr/share/red5/dist/red5.sh` as the tutorial that you have followed.

Then your files should be place in the respective folders which are in dist folder.

Edit reason: bold style did not allowed in the code statement. So removed the double stars before and end at the 'dist/'

Answer (score 0):

Install RED5:
Change directory to your install parent directory, extract the tar file, create a link:

```
cd /usr/local
tar xvfz red5-whateverversion.tgz
ln -s red5-whateversion red5
```

Change directory into your install path - this is crucial:

```
cd /usr/local/red5
```

Drop your firewall rules for testing purposes

```
iptables -F
```

Run the red5 startup script

```
./red5.sh
```

Test port 5080 with telnet on the local server

```
telnet localhost 5080
```

Once you are able to connect to port 5080 from localhost it is working! Typical browser issues are:

your firewall/proxy is blocking port 5080

your DNS server does not have the correct name for your RED5 server

your network does not have the correct routes to/from your PC browser to your RED5 server